# Some Buttons and links not working in bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

i am barely a front end developer and using readily availble snippets for my front end. Im currently facing an issue whereby buttons and links do not work in my footer, here is some of my code:

## base.html

```
  <!-- Footer Links -->
  <div class="container" style="padding-top: 30px;">
    <!-- Grid row -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4">
        <!-- Content -->
        <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold" style="color: #AAAAAA;">{{settings.sitesettings.CompanySettings.company_name}}</h6>
        <p style="color: #fff;">{{settings.sitesettings.CompanySettings.company_subtitle}}</p>
        <hr style="color: white;">
        <div>
          <h6 style="color: #AAAAAA;">{{settings.sitesettings.CompanySettings.company_social_media_title}}
          </h6>
          {%for icon in settings.sitesettings.CompanySettings.company_social_media.all%}
          {%image icon.social_media_icon fill-30x30 as icon%}
          <a href="google.com"><img src="{{icon.url}}" alt="{{icon.alt}}" style="width:10% ;height:auto;back"/></a>            -->#this is not working.
          {%endfor%}
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Grid column -->
      {%for loop_cycle in settings.sitesettings.CompanySettings.footer_settings.all%}
      <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
        <!-- Links -->
        <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold" style="color: #AAAAAA;">{{loop_cycle.footer_header}}</h6>
        {%for link in loop_cycle.footer_links.all%}
        <p>
          <a href="{%pageurl link.link%}" style="color: #fff;">{{link.link_display_name}}</a>  -->#this is somehow working.
        </p>
        {%endfor%}
      </div>
      {%endfor%}
      <!-- Grid column -->

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
        <!-- Links -->
        <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold" style="color: #AAAAAA;">Contact</h6>
        <p style="color: #fff;">
          <i class="fa fa-home mr-3"></i> {{settings.sitesettings.CompanySettings.company_address}}</p>
        <p style="color: #fff;">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope mr-3"></i> {{settings.sitesettings.CompanySettings.company_email}}</p>
          {%for contact in settings.sitesettings.CompanySettings.company_phone.all%}
        <p style="color: #fff;">
          <i class="fa fa-phone mr-3"></i> {{contact.phone}}</p>
        <p>
          {%endfor%}
      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

    </div>
    <!-- Grid row -->
  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="text-center py-3" style="color: white;">
    © 2020 Copyright:
    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/" style="color: white;"> google.com</a>    -->#this is not working.
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->

</footer>
```

Its confusing as it works in certain columns but not on others. Another confusing thing is that the links works for the social media icon links in a mobile viewport. Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The links show up but don't open pages? or The links don't show up at all? One thing is to make sure you aren't using an ad-blocker on your localhost.

Comment: Its not "clickable" , it appears but it doesn't do anythng

Comment: What does the "View Source" show for the non-working links?

Comment: Hello just to confirm view source as in inspect the elements?  <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/" style="color: white;"> google.com</a>

Comment: sorry if i misunderstood ^

Comment: Yeah, I was curious to make certain the underlying code was there. You may just need to make sure that you have "https://" at the beginning of your href= in the <a> tag. Otherwise the browser will just think that is a page on the current site, not a different website. `<a href="https://mdbootstrap.com" style="color: white;"> google.com</a>`

Comment: hmms , i placed a https  , but it still doesn't seem to work , im really lost..